# Trying to build a SQL view but my JOINS only work up to a certain point

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, sql-view

I have been trying to build a view with multiple tables and everything works fine until that last Join.  The reasoning behind creating mytickets and nextStep seperate, was to avoid locking issues as much as possible, as nextStep will be updated far less than the mytickets.

I just want to join the Assignlist to the rest of the tables where I can get 2392 Rows and not 99.330 rows

mytickets has state and country ->

Table Country has 250 Rows
country has Country.ISO and country.ID ->

```
CIDNo   Continent   SubContinent    CountryName ISO
1   Africa  North Africa    Algeria DZA
2   Africa  Middle Africa   Angola  AGO
3   Africa  West Africa Benin   BEN
4   Africa  South Africa    Botswana    BWA
5   Africa  West Africa Burkina Faso    BFA
6   Africa  East Africa Burundi BDI
```

Table [AssignedList] has 314 Rows
AssignedList has Country.ID, State
        ALIDNo  CIDNo   State
    1   1   Algeria
    2   2   Angola
    3   3   Benin
    4   4   Botswana
    5   5   Burkina Faso
    6   6   Burundi
    7   7   Cameroon

```
Table **MyTickets**  has 2392

Table **NextStep**   has 2392
```

When I try the following, I end up with 3000+ rows.

Thanks in advance.

```
    SELECT tx.cSystem + '-' + tx.cTicketNo AS cSysTicket, tx.cTicketStatus, 
    tx.nBDO, tx.cTicketType, 
       tx.cCompany, tx.cState, tx.cCountry, tx.cLastStatus, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
     tx.dSpUpDate, GETDATE()) AS tSpTimer, 
       tx.cAddressSP, nx.nIdNo, tx.cW2Tech, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tx.dUpLoad, 
      GETDATE()) AS dUploaded,
       nx.cEmCode, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), nx.dFollowUp) AS tNextStepTimer, 
      CONVERT(nvarchar(20), 
       nx.dFollowUp, 0) AS dFollowUp, nx.cComments, nx.nUserId, 
    --al.WorkBy1, al.WorkBy2, al.WorkBy3, al.WorkBy4, al.WorkBy5, al.WorkBy6
    --CASE WHEN nx.nUserId = 0 THEN 'SYSTEM UPDATE' ELSE ag.FullName END AS 
     Agent, co.CIDNo
     INNER JOIN dbo.NexStep AS nx 
    ON tx.cSystem + tx.cTicketNo = nx.cSystem + nx.cTicketNo
```

-- Runs with 2392 Rows
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Agents AS ag 
        ON ag.AIDNo = nx.nUserId
-- Runs with 2392 Rows
         INNER JOIN dbo.Country AS co 
-- Runs with 2392 Rows
        ON tx.cCountry = co.ISO 
--**FAILS HERE I end up with 99330 Rows**
       INNER JOIN dbo.AssignedList AS al 
        ON co.CIDNo = al.CIDNo

Comment: Your SQL snippet has no FROM clause; the join should probably be on "(tx.cSystem = nx.cSystem and tx.cTicketNo =  nx.cTicketNo)"

Comment: Also, it might help to simplify the select by removing all the explicit field names and just use * for this example; also, table names can't be surrounded with astrix so remove those from the name

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the last join with this and it worked perfectly where 107 = USA and 68 = CAN:

```
  dbo.AssignedList AS al ON co.CIDNo = al.CIDNo AND CASE WHEN co.CIDNo IN (107, 68) THEN tx.cState ELSE '' END = CASE WHEN co.CIDNo IN (107, 68) THEN al.State ELSE '' END
```